# Install Kubernetes Go Client

Tags: go, kubernetes

I'm trying to install Go Client for Kubernetes. I'm following that  [installation link](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/INSTALL.md). Here is the output:

```
root@c085ca4b6124:/app# GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=1 go get -v k8s.io/client/go/...
Fetching https://k8s.io/client/go?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://k8s.io/client/go?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "k8s.io/client/go": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"k8s.io/client", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://github.com/kubernetes/client"} at https://k8s.io/client/go?go-get=1
get "k8s.io/client/go": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://k8s.io/client?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://k8s.io/client?go-get=1 (status code 200)
k8s.io/client (download)
Username for 'https://github.com': ***
Password for 'https://***@github.com': ***
# cd .; git clone https://github.com/kubernetes/client /go/src/k8s.io/client
Cloning into '/go/src/k8s.io/client'...
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/kubernetes/client/' not found
package k8s.io/client/go/...: exit status 128
root@c085ca4b6124:/app#
```

I can't really get what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in your package name client-go

`# GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=1 go get -v k8s.io/client-go/...`

instead of

`# GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=1 go get -v k8s.io/client/go/...`